# Can't install Jenkins in OS-X <Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war>

Tags: macos, jenkins, terminal

I am trying to install Jenkins in my mac and i have followed this below steps:

1. Downloaded the Jenkins war file for OS-X
2. After cd , Ran this:

   java -jar jenkins.war
3. getting this error in my terminal:

   Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war

Any idea what i am doing wrong??? FYI, I was successful in windows by following those steps.

Comment: I have just now figured out and resolved the issue. Earlier I downloaded the wrong file. :)

Comment: You could elaborate on how you got it working and post it as an answer to yourself - I'm sure it will help someone down the track!

Comment: Don't forget to include some specs of your system and I think the most important will be to include `java` version too! (will help others)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how the issue got resolved. If you got mac or windows regardless,

1. go to jenkins-ci.org
2. Select long term support release which is a stable build.
3. Click on the link .war
4. Then in Terminal cd to that path where you downloaded
5. Run this command: java -jar jenkins.war

You are good to go!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with `java -jar jenkins.war` but when I changed it to `java -jar .\jenkins.war` it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following is running in terminal.

1. $: jenkins
   (You will see the "Running from: ".../jenkins/2.265/libexec/jenkins.war")
2. $: cd .../jenkins/2.265/libexec
3. $: java -jar jenkins.war

Answer (score -2):

Try to run: java -jar jenkins.war.jar. It helped me on Windows 10.

Comment: He said he got it to work on windows but not macOS